# Как восстановить привязку?

Tags: c#, wpf

TreeView заполняется программно при помощи ObservableCollection. Привязка устанавливается в том числе и на открытие-закрытие Items TreeView, что бы открывать Item-ы в том числе и из другой формы. Так вот если щелкнуть мышкой по раскрывающемуся списку любого из Items его привязка к свойству isExpander исчезает, а к Foreground останется. Как восстановить привязку для этого Item-a.

```
public class NodeNap: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ..........
    public string Foreground
    {
        get { return foreground; }
        set { NotifiyPropertyChanged(ref foreground, value); }
    }

    protected bool isExpander = false;
    public bool IsExpander
    {
        get { return isExpander; }
        set { NotifiyPropertyChanged(ref isExpander, value); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected bool NotifiyPropertyChanged<NodeNap>(ref NodeNap oldValue, NodeNap newValue, [CallerMemberName]string property = "")
    {
        oldValue = newValue;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        return true;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<NodeNap> node;
    public ObservableCollection<NodeNap> Node
    {
        get
        {
            if (node == null) node = new ObservableCollection<NodeNap>();
            return node;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот так привязываюсь в коде:

```
private ObservableCollection<NodeNap> node = new ObservableCollection<NodeNap>();
public ObservableCollection<NodeNap> Node { get;set; }

    void Node.Add()
    {
        NodeNap root = new NodeNap(++ID, 0, ((ComboBox)sender).Text)
        {
            IsExpander = true,
            Foreground = "Yellow"
        };

        comboBox1.Text = root.Nap;
        bin1 = new Binding
        {
            Source = root,
            Path = new PropertyPath("Nap"),
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
        };
        comboBox1.SetBinding(ComboBox.TextProperty, bin1);

        Node.Add(root);

        NodeNap child = new NodeNap();
        root.Node.Add(child);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы уверены, что ваш код вообще компилируется?

Comment: Ну и я вижу привязку ComboBox.Text к какому-то Nap. Как это должно работать, я не понимаю совсем.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за развернутый ответ. Вы предлагаете другой подход в организации класса узла дерева. И я вижу, что привязка остается на месте. Возможно мне придется изменить свой код.. Моя задача усложняется тем, что узлы дерева формируются из другой-дочерней формы и набираемый текст синхронно выводится в treeView, при помощи привязки. Тут я запутался - полезли всякие не стыковки. Я не программист, а любитель и с WPF только начинаю разбираться. Пока буду разбирать ваш материал. Отпишусь позже.

Comment: @АлексДронго Я добавил в ответ немного информации о "Вы предлагаете другой подход" и "из другой формы". Что касается "Я не программист" - пишите код, значит им и являетесь, я тоже человек без какого либо специального образования, обычный самоучка и у меня это как хобби изначально было. А писать код, надо с самого начала правильно, приучаться к этому с "пеленок". P.S. Пожалуйста, пишите комментарий ПОД моим ответом, хорошо, что я зашел сюда, ибо оповещений я не каких не получаю (пока не стану "участником" данной беседы и не оставлю комментарий).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы делаете что то совершенно не то, привязку лучше делать через XAML, а не код. Также привязка осуществляется путем указания DataContext.

Давайте разберем как все должно быть:

### INotifyPropertyChanged и ViewModel:

Для начала нам понадобиться базовый класс, который будет реализовывать INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Затем, напишем некий класс, который будет содержать внутри все свойства для привязки:

```
public class TreeViewModel : VM
{
    public TreeViewModel(string name, string foreground = "black", bool isExpander = false, ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel> children = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        Foreground = foreground;
        IsExpander = isExpander;

        if (children != null)
            Children = children;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string foreground;
    public string Foreground
    {
        get => foreground;
        set
        {
            foreground = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool isExpander;
    public bool IsExpander
    {
        get => isExpander;
        set
        {
            isExpander = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel> Children { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel>();
}
```

Что мы тут видим? А все просто, реализуем свойства Name, Foreground, IsExpander, а также коллекцию того же типа для дочерних элементов. У необходимых свойств (те, что могут измениться в ходе работы программы) мы реализуем INPC (что бы наш интерфейс мог эти изменения принять). Собственно все по стандарту. А да, еще для удобства задаем всем свойствам нужные значения.

### Заполнение и DataContext

Я лично буду все делать прям в MainWindow, но по хорошему все это надо делать в отдельной VM.

- Создаем внутри класса MainWindow свойство нашей коллекции (для привязки лучше использовать ObservableCollection, ибо она реализует все необходимое для обновления интерфейса):

  ```
  public ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel>();
  ```
- Ну и прям в конструкторе MainWindow (повторюсь, это не совсем правильно, лучше использовать отдельную VM!) заполняем тестовыми данными, ну и сразу задаем DataContext. Должно получиться что то вроде этого:

  ```
  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

      var languages = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel>()
      {
          new TreeViewModel("Русский"),
          new TreeViewModel("Английский", "Red"),
          new TreeViewModel("Испанский")
      };

      Items.Add(new TreeViewModel("Языки", isExpander: true, children: languages));

      var people = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel>()
      {
          new TreeViewModel("Вася"),
          new TreeViewModel("Маша"),
          new TreeViewModel("Вова", children: new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel>{new TreeViewModel("Аня")})
      };

      Items.Add(new TreeViewModel("Люди", "Blue", children: people));

      DataContext = this;
  }
  ```

Для теста я лично еще добавлю кнопку и на клик повешу ей изменение IsExpander у второго элемента коллекции:

```
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items[1].IsExpander = !Items[1].IsExpander;
    }
```

### XAML разметка:

И так, финишная прямая! Нам осталось создать View со всеми необходимыми нам элементами, в моем случае нужно создать TreeView и Button:

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpander, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>

    <Button Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Открыть/Закрыть" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
</Grid>
```

С Button все понятно я думаю, а вот TreeView по сложнее:

- Первым делом мы привязываем TreeView к нашей коллекции (которую заполняли) через ItemsSource.
- Далее мы задаем стиль для элементов типа TreeViewItem. В нем мы привязываем свойство IsExpanded. Заметьте, используется `Mode=TwoWay` - что позволяет отслеживать изменения, произведенные с данным свойством как со стороны интерфейса, так и со стороны кода.
- Далее мы задаем HierarchicalDataTemplate, это некий шаблон, который задает формат отображения уровня данных. В нем мы указываем тип, который используется в привязанной коллекции (через DataType), задаем дочернюю привязку элементов (через ItemsSource), ну и привязываем цвет и имя.

Вот собственно и все, результатом будет что то на подобие этого:

[image: Result]

---

> Моя задача усложняется тем, что узлы дерева формируются из другой-дочерней формы и набираемый текст синхронно выводится в treeView, при помощи привязки.

Вот для этого и создается разделение на MVVM. Смотрите, к примеру заполнение коллекции и саму коллекцию Items мы перенесем в некую ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel>();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var languages = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel>()
        {
            new TreeViewModel("Русский"),
            new TreeViewModel("Английский", "Red"),
            new TreeViewModel("Испанский")
        };

        Items.Add(new TreeViewModel("Языки", isExpander: true, children: languages));

        var people = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel>()
        {
            new TreeViewModel("Вася"),
            new TreeViewModel("Маша"),
            new TreeViewModel("Вова", children: new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel>{new TreeViewModel("Аня")})
        };

        Items.Add(new TreeViewModel("Люди", "Blue", children: people));
    }
}
```

Далее, заместо того, что было раньше в MainWindow мы делаем свойство нашей VM и к нему привяжем DataContext (ну и про кнопку не забываем...):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; } = new MainViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = MainViewModel;
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainViewModel.Items[1].IsExpander = !MainViewModel.Items[1].IsExpander;
    }
}
```

Собственно и все, теперь у нас есть отдельная VM, которая отвечает за свой функционал. Как же нам обратиться к ней из другого окна? Смотрите, привязка работает с тем объектом, что был создан ранее и если мы будем инициализировать объект заново (по типу `MainViewModel model = new...`), то вероятней всего потеряем все привязки (я уж не говорю о данных), да и вообще, какой смысл плодить сотню одинаковых объектов? Так вот, наша задача - это передача ссылки в наше новое окно, самый простой вариант, это получать ее в конструкторе нового окна:

```
public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }

public Window2(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainViewModel = mainViewModel;
}
```

Ну и дальше вызов из первого окна будет примерно такой (но тут я не уверен в MVVM, лучше это завязывать на эвенты и тому подобное):

```
Window2 window2 = new Window2(MainViewModel);
window2.Show();
```

Вот собственно и все, таким образом у нас передается ссылка на нашу VM в нужное окно, где мы с ней спокойно можем работать. Привязка в этом случае не как не затронется.

> Вы предлагаете другой подход в организации класса узла дерева.

Давайте поговорим на эту тему...
Я вам предлагаю правильный подход, то, что обязательно должен знать человек при использование WPF (я про MVVM). Хотите работать с WPF, работайте правильно и используйте MVVM. А сам MVVM подразумевает то, что весь ваш код будет разделен на 3 слоя (Model, ViewModel, и View). Слой View не как не должен быть связан с кодом приложения, он должен только знать, что "тут должен отобразиться объект с именем Name" и все. В первое время это немного напрягает, думаешь "как и что?", но со временем (причем очень быстро) привыкаешь и все другое кажется совершенно неверным подходом. Кстати, я раньше тоже использовал старый подход, лепил все как в WinForms, потом мне здесь помогли с реализацией MVVM и знаете, после того, как я переписал свое старое приложение по новой - оно стало в разы работать шустрее и правильней. В общем, как по мне, без MVVM лучше вовсе не браться за WPF и сидеть на формах...

---

> и набираемый текст синхронно выводится в treeView

За синхронность отвечает `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` в свойствах привязки. Но я так понял, что у вас должна быть какая то логика для работы. Я предположил, что пользователь должен ввести текст, если находит совпадение, то редактирует его. Как сделать?

Создадим еще одну ViewModel, в ней мы создадим свойство Name для привязки, реализуем INPC и передадим MainViewModel. Код в общем будет примерно такой:

```
public class SecondViewModel : VM
{
    private MainViewModel MainViewModel;

    public SecondViewModel(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        MainViewModel = mainViewModel;
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            name = value;
            Search(value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private TreeViewModel model;

    private void Search(string text)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            model = MainViewModel.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == text);
        }
        else
        {
            model.Name = text;
        }
    }
}
```

Заметьте, я вызываю `Search(value);` при изменение в свойстве Name. Сам метод `Search();` реализует простейшую логику поиска нужного объекта, если объект найден, то сохраняем на него ссылку в ранее подготовленное поле. При дальнейшем обновление - мы будем менять значение Name у найденного объекта.

Привяжем наше второе окно к созданной VM:

```
public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }
public SecondViewModel SecondViewModel { get; set; }

public Window2(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainViewModel = mainViewModel;
    SecondViewModel = new SecondViewModel(mainViewModel);
    DataContext = SecondViewModel;
}
```

Ну и в XAML сделаем привязку:

*внимание на UpdateSourceTrigger!

В итоге у нас получится что то вроде этого:

[image: Result 2]

Вроде все, как можно заметить - мы изменили в TreeView значение "Языки" на "Языки мира!", причем выводя все это в "реальном времени". Остается только реализовать кнопку сохранения и пару мелочей, но это уже на вас...

Comment: я понимаю ваш код. Поверьте, мой не на много отличается. Задавая вопрос, я многое удалил из кода, что бы не засорить сам впрос, и наверное этим же я только усложнил все... Я тоже реализую MVVM. Стараюсь по крайней мере. Я знаю, что ваше событие ButtonBase_OnClick нужно пробросить во VM через EventHandler и там его уже обрабатывать. Я так и делаю. У меня тоже в XAML разметке, правда в шаблоне TreeViewItem(т.к. у меня TreeView многоколоночный), биндятся свойства класса(NodeNap), формирующего узлы TreeView.

Comment: Сложность у меня в том, что текст, набираемый в ComboBox-е в дочернем окне (у которого своя VM) синхронно должен выводится в TreeView. ObservableCollection этого сделать не может, т.к. к тому времени еще не создан. Я не нашел ничего лучшего пока, чем в момент изменнеия текста в обработчике во VM TextBoxBase.TextChanged="CmbCat_TextChanged" создать пустой узел и привязать ComboBox.Text к св-ву (у меня Nap) класса формирующего узел во время его создания. Наверное это не правильно.

Comment: Хотя в принципе все работает, кроме того что исчезает привязка, описанная в моем вопросе. Может вы подскажете мне как правельно реализовать мою задумку и избежать подобных косяков. Не судите строго если что, wpf для меня пока это - разрыв мозгов).

Comment: @АлексДронго А вы можете дать скриншот того, что реализуете (с подробным описанием желательно), попробовал бы написать это все грамотно. Ну а вообще, вся ваша проблема в том, что IsExpanded привязывается "в одну сторону" укажите TwoWay и не должна будет слетать.

Comment: Я добавил, только там еще две колонки, просто они не заполнены

Comment: @АлексДронго Я вам могу показать пример привязки к TextBox другого окна и изменений на лету. Остальное думаю вы сами сделаете (создание объекта если нет, выбор объекта итд), ибо я не до конца понимаю вашу задачу, да и не все же мне за вас писать =))

Comment: @АлексДронго Я добавил пример обновления.

Comment: Буду курить ваш код. Много интересной для меня информации. После отпишусь:)

Comment: Подскажите, а базовый класс, который наследует INotifyPropertyChanged, о котором вы говорили в самом начале, это просто базовый класс или VM окна в котором TreeView?

Comment: Или это не важно? И еще вопрос: допустим наш классTreeViewModel имеет некое сво-во Size, но оно не инициализируется через конструктор класса, обработает его ObservableCollection правильно, обновит сво-во при изменении автоматически?

Comment: @АлексДронго VM класс - это просто для удобства всю логику INPC мы вынесли в отдельный класс, который потом просто наследуется и вызывается `OnPropertyChanged();`, где это необходимо. Без этого нам пришлось бы все, что внутри класса VM реализовывать везде, где вызываем `OnPropertyChanged();`. По поводу конструктора - это просто ради удобства. Если есть свойство и к нему сделана привязка, то оно будет обновляться независимо от конструктора.

Comment: EvgeniyZ. Cпс за помощь. Переделываю свой проект, согласно ваших рекомендаций. Свои биндинги из TextChanged я конечно убрал, и пробую организовать создание узлов, синхронный вывод текста и изменение узлов через отдельный класс(как в вашем примере SecondViewModel). Ваша информация очень полезна, предельно ясна и красиво оформлена. Я принял ваш ответ и вопрос с восстановлением привязки закрыт. Могу ли я в дальнейшем обращаться к вам за советом и если да то как? Не зависимо от ответа, в любом случае Большое спасибо)

Comment: @АлексДронго Обратиться можете всегда на этом сайте, задав отдельный вопрос, ну а вообще, все контакты есть на моем [сайте](http://evgeniy-z.ru/contact). Рад что смог помочь, удачи!