# Как сделать Tree на основании таблицы базы данных? - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется таблица MS Access "tbl_TreeView_01_WPF"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал подключение таблицы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перетащил таблицу на "TreeView".
Сейчас получаю TreeView в виде см. скрин.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопросы.**
1. Как сделать чтобы таблица отображалась в виде дерева с оформлением:
- кнопки (свернуть/развернуть) в виде "+/-";
- между узлами соединительные пунктирные линии;
?
2. Как синхронизировать дерево с исходной таблицей?
Т.е. вношу изменения в название узла, а изменения автоматически вносятся в исходную таблицу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="rsh.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:rsh"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:dbAccessTestDataSet x:Key="dbAccessTestDataSet"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="tbl_TreeView_01_WPFViewSource" Source="{Binding tbl_TreeView_01_WPF, Source={StaticResource dbAccessTestDataSet}}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource tbl_TreeView_01_WPFViewSource}">
        <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="354" ItemsSource="{Binding}">

        </TreeView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Код MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace rsh
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            rsh.dbAccessTestDataSet dbAccessTestDataSet = ((rsh.dbAccessTestDataSet)(this.FindResource("dbAccessTestDataSet")));
            // Загрузить данные в таблицу tbl_TreeView_01_WPF. Можно изменить этот код как требуется.
            rsh.dbAccessTestDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_TreeView_01_WPFTableAdapter dbAccessTestDataSettbl_TreeView_01_WPFTableAdapter = new rsh.dbAccessTestDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_TreeView_01_WPFTableAdapter();
            dbAccessTestDataSettbl_TreeView_01_WPFTableAdapter.Fill(dbAccessTestDataSet.tbl_TreeView_01_WPF);
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource tbl_TreeView_01_WPFViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("tbl_TreeView_01_WPFViewSource")));
            tbl_TreeView_01_WPFViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Сейчас получаю TreeView в виде` - вам надо понять как устроен TreeView. В таблице своей вы по сути имеете коллекцию неких элементов, которые содержат определенные значения. В TreeView требуется другой вид, по сути это коллекция, которая содержит коллекцию и в этой коллекции есть еще коллекция. Совпадают ли ваша таблица с требуемым форматом для TreeView? Я думаю нет... Я как то [отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/826606/Как-восстановить-привязку/826727#826727) о том, как правильно реализовать TreeView. Попробуйте реализовать что то подобное и потом уже вносите ваши данные.

Comment: Из названия самого контрола следует, что для него нужна древовидная структура данных, а у вас в данный момент - плоская таблица.

Comment: @Bulson Чё-то я блудю... Эту таблицу я подключил в DevExpres к TreeControl и у меня сразу строится дерево... С "TreeView" это не пройдёт? Нужны дополнительные манипуляции? PS. Прошу извинить, если вопрос некорректен. Только начинаю осваивать программирование. Перечитал кучу материала, но всё равно до конца понять не могу... Мозги уже засорены

Comment: В первом комментарии `EvgeniyZ` уже есть ссылка на ответ, там показано практически все что нужно.

Comment: @Bulson Я пока изучаю ссылку от `EvgeniyZ `.... А есть какие-нибудь готовые инструменты(решения), чтобы таблицу как у меня подключил к контролу и дерево строилось без лишних телодвижений?

Comment: Понимаю. Хочется одну большую красную кнопку - нажал и у-всё готово. Извините, но я не знаю где она. Разве только вы сами ее создадите и поможете таким образом другим.