# Получение текущего элемента в treeView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, treeview

Вопрос в дополнение к вопросу: [Иерархия treeView c 3-м уровнем вложенности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/857822/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F-treeview-c-3-%D0%BC-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment1383691_857822), а именно не понимаю по какой причине не удается получить узел treeViewItem при такой привязке:

Класс Заказчик:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Consignee = new HashSet<Consignee>();
    }

    public int idCustomer { get; set; }
    public string nameCustomer { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Consignee> Consignee { get; set; }
}
```

Класс Полигон:

```
 public partial class Consignee
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Consignee()
    {
        this.Servers = new HashSet<Servers>();
        this.Systems = new HashSet<Systems>();
    }

    public int idConsignee { get; set; }
    public int idCustomerConsignee { get; set; }
    public string nameConsignee { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Servers> Servers { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Systems> Systems { get; set; }
}
```

Код XAML для иерархии Заказчик-Полигон:

```
        <TreeView x:Name="tvForLic">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Consignee}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= nameCustomer}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= nameConsignee}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Преобразование вида выдает null:

```
  TreviewItem item = tvForLic.SelectedItem;
```

Получается необходимо сперва определять уровень узла после приводить к соответствующему типу:

```
  SelectedItem = (Customer)tvForLic.SelectedItem;
```

или

```
  SelectedItem = (Consignee)tvForLic.SelectedItem;
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться:

- как определить уровень вложенности выбранного узла treeView(если сам SelectedItem к типу TreeViewItem не приводиться)?

Таким образом получается, но это очень криво:

```
        switch (tvForLic.SelectedItem)
        {
            case Customer cust:
                SelectedItem = tvForLic.SelectedItem as Customer;
                break;
            case Consignee cons:
                SelectedItem = tvForLic.SelectedItem as Consignee;
                    break;
        }
```

- понимая, что такой подход не совсем корректен, может посоветуете как по шагам (MVVM пока тяжело идет, сложно понять порядок и ключевые моменты и требования к типам) построить корректную привязку?
- может есть требования к приведенным классам (сущностным Entity), которые позволят осуществить выбор выделенного элемента корректным образом?

Comment: Как-то нехорошо вы с TreeView обращаетесь. Я бы сделал так, чтобы все элементы, которые могут выводиться в нем имели какого-то общего предка (хотя бы интерфейс), а все операции, которые должны выполняться с этим элементом или должны быть включены в этот предок или метод, который что-то делает с элементом TreeView, должен принимать параметр типа этого предка.

Comment: @АндрейNOP благодарю Вас за комментарий, но комментарий породил еще больше вопросов.

Comment: Ну вот получаете вы `currentTreeView.SelectedItem` (что такое `currentTreeView`, кстати?) и что вы дальше с этим значением делаете?

Comment: @АндрейNOP currentTreeView это элемент на форме TreeView (скорректировала код в вопросе) . Последовательность его заполнения следующая: В БД есть таблицы и классы, приведенные выше, их описывают. В элемент treeView я передаю класс Consignee. Значение выделенного узла мне необходимо, чтобы осуществлять фильтрацию таблицы и редактирование записи в БД для выделенного объекта.

Comment: Например, выделили узел и далее добавление дочерней записи будет привязываться к этому объекту.

Comment: А если выделено не `Consignee`, а `Customer`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP мой "гений" пришел к коду выше (switch-case). Фильтрация работает, думаю добавление тоже закручу, просто чувствуется убогий подход