# переборка TreeView привязанного к коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Пример, есть класс:

```
class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Test> coll { get; set; }
    public Test()
    {
        coll = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
    }
}
```

Дерево:

```
<TreeView Name="Tree" Margin="0,80,0,0">
```

Коллекция, привязанная к дереву:

```
    ObservableCollection<Test> testColl = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
```

Задача такова, что я хочу в коде, из определённых значений параметров test в коллекции, открывать и выделять ветки дерева, но я не знаю как перебрать дерево и все TreeViewItem'ы. 
Пробовал подобное, но ругается на преобразование Test в TreeViewItem.

```
foreach (TreeViewItem tvi in Tree.Items)
            {
                tvi.IsExpanded = true;
                tvi.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
             }
```

Для начала просто хотел узнать, как можно перебрать дерево, по TreeViewItem, привязанное к коллекции.

Comment: Так вам для всех элементов надо свойства задать или только для некорых в зависимости от привязанных данных?

Comment: Только для некоторых, но если есть возможность показать как в цикле для всех задать, я буду только рад.

Comment: Не надо циклов, надо привязки, шаблоны, триггеры и конвертеры. Вот это всё.

Comment: Может, тогда подскажешь почему триггер из прошлой моей темы не срабатывает??? DependencyProperty на "flag" прописал. Или скажи где копать? Толковых примеров с DataTrigger не видел

Comment: Да здесь куча примеров уже, почитайте это, например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/826727/218063

Comment: Спасибо за последний пример, я наконец-то разобрался как это работает. Спасибо ещё раз.